# node version error while pushing to Git repository

Tags: node.js, gitlab

I'm getting this error while pushing my updates to git repository.

Some possible problems:

```
   - Node version not specified in package.json
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

   Love,
   Heroku
```

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 134

I'm using git push origin master

same I used before

and this is mu pakage json file

```
"name": "lc-portal",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "MY APP",
"main": "server/start.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon --watch server -e js,html server/start.js",
"postinstall": "gulp build"
}
```

Why I'm getting this error suddenly couldn't fine relevant solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the node version

```
"engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  },
```

Replace "10.x" with your version.

Your `package.json` file should be like

```
{
    "name": "lc-portal",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "MY APP",
    "main": "server/start.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon --watch server -e js,html server/start.js",
        "postinstall": "gulp build"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "your_node_version"
    }
}
```

Follow the [heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)

Comment: but after i add try to pull the code it gives me this error even after i commit --- error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        package.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting

Comment: Since you changed the file `package.json`, you have to commit. Try `git add .` `git commit -m 'add node engine'` then `push` again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the "engines" field:

```
{ "engines" : { "node" : ">=8" } }
```

If your code definitely won't work with any lower versions, you probably want the "engineStrict" flag too:

```
{ "engineStrict" : true }
```

Documentation for the package.json file can be found on the [npmjs site](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines)